# Data recovery from partition, that Ubu formatted during install

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-loss

My Ubuntu system broke up few weeks ago and there was not another way than reinstall. As I do not have anything that big as my data values on HDD, I parted the disk to two similarly sized partitions. One sda(X) and one with a label YY, where was my backup. When I booted up live USB partitions could be seen. I began with installation and chose to install ubuntu instead of xx system there was before. I had no idea, that Ubu would reformat whole HDD to install itself. And so as it was my work computer and I am a CEO at the company, there were too many valuable data that I can not afford to lose.

Is there a way to recover at least something? What do I need to do so?

Thank You very much

Comment: I found a very in depth recovery process in the Ubuntu documentation site at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery Please try the steps described there.